# Difference between code generation and model-to-text transformation

Tags: model, code-generation, transformation

I am trying to understand the concrete difference between code generation from a model (e.g. using EMF) and model-to-text transformations using e.g. Acceleo or Xpand. Both concepts use models as input, and the output is the code, that is based on the model, along with e.g. editors etc. I haven't used any of the M2T-frameworks until now, and that's why I am having some problems understanding the practical differences between those two concepts. Could please someone enlighten me in that matter, a head-to-head comparison would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different conceptually.

**MODEL-TO-TEXT** transformation is the process (technique) of extracting code from a model. This tranformation could be defined in several ways, depending on your source metamodel and your destination language. It's the opposite of TEXT-TO-MODEL, that extracts a model analysing the source code.

For instance, you can extract and generate Java code from a UML in a MODEL-TO-TEXT transformation.

**Acceleo**, for example, is a tool based on standars which makes you possible to make a tranformation MODEL-TO-TEXT. Acceleo needs model (maybe in .xml format or the standar .xmi) and some templates (.mtl) that you define.

With these templates and the Acceleo engine you will be able to parse your model and generate the code you need.

To sum up: **MODEL-TO-TEXT is a process, and Acceleo is a tool to develop and run the process.**

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But so much is already clear to me. What I am trying to understand is the logical difference between, let's say, generating the model code from an Ecore model using EMF and transforming a model in xml format into (e.g. Java) code using Acceleo. Of course, using two different frameworks, your process of achieving the desired results will also be different. But beside that, why should one choose one concept and its implementation against another? Where do generating code from model and transforming a model into code differ?

Comment: I can't find the difference, @DanglishElse. I think we are talking about the same thing, in different words. I've studied theory about this (because of a project I'm developing right now) and I can't see the difference. For me, I work with Acceleo because I can go deeper in the transformation and make it in the way I am. But I think it's not about the results or the process... it's up to you or your team's abilities, knowledge etc. I hope I've explained better now

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention you well. @DanglingElse

Comment: I also can't see any differences between these two concepts, beside how they work etc. It seems that both concepts realize the same kind of outputs (code) from same kind of inputs (model). But there must be something different in-between. I can't think that they differ only in terminology. OK, EMF is a framework for creating models and it also provides the back-end to generate code from these models, but why isn't it called model-to-text transformation, because it's main aspect is to model? Also EMF isn't the only tool to generate code from models. So as you can see, I am little bit confused.

Comment: EMF gives you Java from a Model among other features. Acceleo has several different modules for each transformation (UML2Java, UML2C or whatever), and lets you to develop your own module as I do. Developing your module you will be able to customize your transformation. But, I insist, they are different tools, no different concepts. For instance: what are the differences between Eclipse/Visual Studio/NetBeans etc. They are different in use, but no in their meaning.